# Is there a way to get an azure portal url to a specific workflow in a standard logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azureportal, azure-logic-app-standard

I don't think this is possible,
but i would like to know if there is any url that can re-direct me to a specific workflow in a standard logic app (single-tenant).

Why do i ask this, because in the consumption logic apps, if i provided someone with the url, they would go directly to the overview page where they would have information about the run history of the workflow and could trigger it.

That's not the case with standard logic apps. If i provide someone with an url, they would go to the logic app resource and not the workflow/s page.
Azure doesn't seem to change the url if i click on workflows.

I guess they're missing this functionality? Or is there a way to turn around this?

Comment: One of the workarounds is to share them with the workflow's code view, masking the subscription so that they can use the same code view in their logic app and can see the flow. https://i.imgur.com/YgkcLz2.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try the following steps:**

1. Navigate to the Logic App (Standard) Blade on your Azure
   Subscription.
2. Click on the "Workflows" menu on the left pane. This will list all your Logic App (Standard) Workflows.
3. Right-click on the corresponding workflow link you wish to get the direct url for. (Check the image further below for reference) .
4. Click "Copy link address" from your browser context menu.

> **Voila!** You should get a direct link to the corresponding Standard Logic App Workflow's overview page.

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Here is a sample URL format of a Logic App (Standard) Workflow:
https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_EMA/WorkflowMenuBlade/resourceId/%2Fsubscriptions%2Fxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx%2FresourceGroups%2Fmy-resourcegroup%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Web%2Fsites%2Fmy-standard-logicapp-name%2Fworkflows%2Fmy-workflow-name/location/East%20US

*Note: This URL format is for reference only. Please attempt the steps mentioned above to get the accurate url to the Workflow Overview page.*

Comment: What a simple and elegant solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no such functionality that redirects to workflow, but one workaround that we can consider is to share the User with the code view while masking the Subscription and your resource group, so they could use the same code view to view the workflow of your logic app in their subscription and resource group.

Here is a sample code view

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['ProcedureName']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Compose_2": {
                "inputs": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['name']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Insert_row_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "name": "Sample Name",
                        "surname": "Sample Surname"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('[dbo].[Students]'))}/items"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@body('Insert_row_(V2)')",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "ProcedureName": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "name": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "surname": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Insert_row_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "sql": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<YOUR SUBSCRIPTION ID>/resourceGroups/<YOUR RESOURCE GROUP>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql",
                    "connectionName": "sql",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<YOUR SUBSCRIPTION ID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northcentralus/managedApis/sql"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```